# Problems copying files in python

Tags: python, copying

I have been trying to write a program to get all my .cpp files from the documents/VisualStudio2008 folder, but I am having trouble copying them to the desktop. I want it move all the .cpp from a specified folder to the desktop. I have a standardized naming scheme and I have done everything I can think of. Any help is appreciated. The code is below, if you need any more info, just ask.

```
import shutil, os

src = ""
dest = ""
chapter = 0
type = ["StepByStep", "Project", "Activity"]
currentType = 0

chapter = int (input("What chapter files would you like to get?\n>> "))
destFolder = input("What do you want the folder name to be?\n>> ")

dest = "C:/Users/17haydent/desktop/"
src = "C:/Users/17haydent/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/"
#srcEnd = name/name/name.cpp


def upType():
    global currentType
    if currentType == 0:
        currentType = 1
    elif currentType == 1:
        currentType = 2

dest += destFolder

for a in range(1, 3):
    for b in range(1, 20):
        newSrc = src + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_'  + str(b) + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + ".cpp"
       newDest = dest + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + ".cpp"
    try:
        assert not os.path.isabs(newSrc)
        dstdir =  os.path.join(newDest, os.path.dirname(newSrc))

        os.makedirs(dstdir) # create all directories, raise an error if it already exists
        shutil.copyfile(newSrc, dstdir)
    except:
        print("Error copying file", newSrc, "to", newDest)
upType()
```

Comment: You introduced your scenario, and gave code. But what is the problem? What is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the `try:` at the same indentation level as `newDest = ...`?

I.e.:

```
for b in range(1, 20):
    newSrc = src + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_'  + str(b) + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + ".cpp"
    newDest = dest + '/' + type[currentType] + str(chapter) + '_' + str(b) + ".cpp"
    try:
        assert not os.path.isabs(newSrc)
```

etc.

Otherwise only the last file will get copied.